# Exception in setDataSource() method in MediaPlayer Android

Tags: android, listview, android-intent, mp3, media-player

My Mp3 app has 2 intents. The code is for the 2nd Intent.

In the previous Intent of my Mp3 app, all the available songs are displayed in the ListView and their paths are saved in ArrayList. The previous Intent searches a song, add it's path in the ArrayList and then searches for the next song and so on. Then I am passing the whole ArrayList of paths and position of the song in the ListView to use it as the index for ArrayList fp in the 2nd intent.

This program (i.e. the 2nd intent) extracts path of mp3 file and it's position in ListView from the Previous Intent. Now I'm facing problem of playing that song using MediaPlayer class. Exception has occurred in the setDataSource() method.

```
public class PlayerScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

private Intent intent;
private Bundle bndl;                                                    
private ArrayList<String> fp = new ArrayList<String>();
private int ps;
private MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_player_screen);

    intent = this.getIntent();
    bndl = intent.getExtras();
    fp = bndl.getStringArrayList("path");
    ps = bndl.getInt("pos");
    File file = new File(fp.get(ps));
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(fp.get(ps)));
    FileInputStream inputStream = null;
    try {
        inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        mp.setDataSource(inputStream.getFD());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        mp.prepare();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mp.start();
}
}
```

**--------- beginning of crash
09-26 03:00:07.126 1161-1161/prakhar.simplemusicplayer E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                        Process: prakhar.simplemusicplayer, PID: 1161
                        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{prakhar.simplemusicplayer/prakhar.simplemusicplayer.PlayerScreen}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(java.io.FileDescriptor)' on a null object reference
                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2426)
                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490)
                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:154)
                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354)
                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(java.io.FileDescriptor)' on a null object reference
                        at prakhar.simplemusicplayer.PlayerScreen.onCreate(PlayerScreen.java:42)
                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6259)
                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1130)
                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490) 
                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:154) 
                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354) 
                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443) 
                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728) 
                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)**

Comment: You already set the datasource in the media player "create", the create() method sets the data source and prepares automatically - don't use the create() method and then call prepare() .. also don't define mp outside of onCreate() leave it as `private MediaPlayer mp;` and then inside onCreate() define it `mp = ...`

Comment: It worked!
Thankyou!